# Make an if-else condition state inside php with an element array [[["5"]]]

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I want to create an if-else statement inside in a php file but i faced a serious problem. Look at the code below:

**first.php**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "mysql3");
// Check connection
if($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user_id =$_POST['user_id'];
$book_id =$_POST['book_id'];
$game_id =$_POST['game_id'];
$site_id =$_POST['site_id'];

//Attempt insert query execution
$query = "SELECT site_id FROM components WHERE user_id='$user_id' && book_id='$book_id' && game_id='$game_id' ORDER BY site_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$result = array();

//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
//array_push($result, array($row[0]));}
//echo json_encode(array($result));

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

When I echo the result (I believe that my output is $result - if I am wrong tell me) then my browser shows me this value  **[[["5"]]]**. Is it possible to have an array inside an array? How can i manipulate this element (for example 5, 3, whatever) in order to make an if-else statement?

Is there a way?

Comment: Those are called Multi-Dimensional -Arrays. You can read about them and how to use them [here](https://www.elated.com/articles/php-multidimensional-arrays/).

Comment: @D.Schaller thank you for your feedback! Very useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fetch_assoc()` for lighter array iteration:-

```
$result = array();
$res = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $result[]=$row['site_id'];
}
print_r($result);//for checking purpose
```

To manipulate this array you can do:-

```
if($result[0] <20){
  echo "Have a good day!";
}
```

Comment: thank you! If i want to manipulate this, should i do this?  if ($result < "20") { echo "Have a good day!"; }

Comment: @TonyDs  i have added solution for that

Comment: Yes! @Alive to Die. You have absolute right. Works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. I accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  $result[]=$row[0];
}
//manipulate here
if ($result[0] < "20"){
  echo "Have a good day!"; 
} 
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Indeed, now it shows me this ["5"]. If i want to manipulate this is this right? 
if ($result < "20") {
    echo "Have a good day!";
}

Comment: where you want to do that? @TonyDs

Comment: Thank you @Bhargav Chudasama. I want to do this because my goal is to make a redirection to another page if this value is the right value that i want. Thank you again.